# convert typedef unsigned char to bytes

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I am getting this value as a response  in my JNI class -

```
 pMgaData =  "\xb5b\x13@\x18"
```

its data type is UBX_U1* which a typedef unsigned char

now I have to convert it into bytes so that I can put into byte array and return it to my java class...please help

I have already tried this but not helping

```
 jobject *f = (jobject *) jenv->GetDirectBufferAddress(bufferpassed_fromjavaclass);

            *f = (jobject)pMgaData;  // pMgdata is the value which i need to cast (unsigned char)
```

Comment: What's `bufferpassed_fromjavaclass`? In Java arrays are of fixed length, you can't create an empty array and fill it later. I'd assume you're going to create a byte array at C++ side and pass it to Java side, is it what you're trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing byte array from native code to the Java side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518855/passing-byte-array-from-native-code-to-the-java-side)